# can the location of my employment block the use of my hot spot?

Tags: blocking, hotspot

Can the location of my employment block the use of my hot spot?  I cannot access either 3G or 4G internet at work with my hotspot.

Comment: I once worked in a building where I couldn't even get 1 bar on my old flip phone, though I would get full strength outside.  (Sunlight didn't penetrate that building either.)  And that didn't involve intentional jamming.  Some places (eg, theaters) use jammers.

Comment: My workplace is like a [Faraday cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage).  Steel frame, reflective windows.  My phone loses all signal inside.  Yes, it's possible they are blocking your hot spot with some sort of [jammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_jammer), but it's more likely the building is a steel cage.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, absolutely. I receive full bars and 4G on my mobile phone, but when I try tethering, it wouldn't work. I can connect my laptop to my phone internet outside of my office building, therefore they must have some sort of a block.

Comment: There are cell blockers, but right now they're illegal in most countries that I'm aware of, except for law enforcement use. The construction of a building could affect the ability to receive certain frequencies, but your description of your issue doesn't match that. There are also several other much more likely causes of what you are experiencing, and based on what you've written, there is no evidence to link your described symptoms with your stated finding.